# Root profile page for club in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For a club page I am wanting to provide a url to them like the following. Am using .net 5 and ef core as well.

I am storing the url for each club in the database which is a striped version the the club Name field.

[www.yoursite.com/clubpage](http://www.yoursite.com/clubpage)

I have a controller obv with the action method and the controller is called ClubController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string url) {
  var club = _context.Clubs
  .Where(w => w.isActive == true && w.Url == url && w.isDeleted == 
   false).ToList();
}
```

Question is what do i need in my config mapping to allow the url style but still allow the other controllers to function

Can I have multiple useend points statement's or am i over complicating by not just having [www.yoursite.com/club/clubpage](http://www.yoursite.com/club/clubpage)?

My startup configuration.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
}
```

If I should do the latter why is must my parameter always be Id?

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string url) {
        return (IActionResult)_context.Clubs.Where(w => w.isActive == true && w.Url == url && w.isDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault();            
    }
```

**Edit 2**
Ok this got me to where i needed to be but is their way to take it step futher and remove the club just the name?.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "club",
 pattern: "club/{clubname?}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Club", action = "Index" });
```

When I have this I would still like club to be able to go to say /Club/Timeline but with the above root also it doesnt allot me it just keeps going to index.

**Edit 3**

If I do the following it allows me to have both scenarios but i feel i shouldn't need to do both?

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "TimeLine",
  pattern: "Club/TimeLine/{clubname?}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Club", action = "ClubTimeLine" });

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Club",
  pattern: "Club/{clubname?}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Club", action = "Club" });
```

Comment: `it doesnt allot me it just keeps going to index.`If you set the action=Index,it must get into the Index action by default when you run the application.Not sure what is your requirement now,Could you please explain more clear about your requirement?

Comment: @Rena Basically am still wanting to hit the other ./Club Controller actions be edit or details what i have had to do in mean time is to adjust my Club one and give other functions there own route seems only way around it. Its so it can be testdomain.com/club/clubname but then it could still go to testdomain.com/club/edit/2 etc

Comment: @Rena see edit 3

Comment: From your edit 3,it seems you create two templates and you want to combine them to one template.Please share the url and corresponding action.How do they match?We cannot help you if you only share the route template.

Comment: The route templates are their ! in edit 3